# How to clean a domestic air conditioner

Tags: air-conditioning, rust

How do I clean the inside of a domestic air conditioner? Can I spray water to the coil (after the filters are off) or water will make coil to get rust?

Comment: i have an air conditioner that was salvaged from a flooded basement. completely flooded. i got it about 10 years ago, have used it about 6 summers, and it still works. make sure it's dry before you plug it back in and you should be golden.

Answer (score 0):

The coil gets water (condensate from the air) on it all the time in use, so putting water on it should not affect it. How effective that will be in cleaning it is another issue, and "where else you get water" while spraying it could be a problem, but as to your question, "**No, the coil is perfectly fine being wet, happens all the time.**"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes actually I am not sure if I asked it correctly. I just don't want to affect the refrigerant gas in any way. I mean I don't know how leaks are made in AC so that's why I am asking. After the filters are out. there is an iron thing. I will spray there as I don't have access anywhere else that I can clean. But before I do that, I would like to know if it's safe to do

Answer (score 0):

There are commercial spray cans of cleaning liquid for evaporator coils. I have used some and it seemed to work , but I do not remember the name. Our coil lasted 22+ years before apparently dying . Any coils I have seen are aluminum so they do not "rust".If you have red rust , it is coming from the galvanized steel water collection pan .

Answer (score 0):

In addition to coils, I sprayed mine clean with water, take the cooling unit out of its housing so you can get at the area where water pools on the bottom of the unit. After a few years, this area tends to fill with massive quantities of mold. I sprayed mine out in the tub. You might do better taking the thing outside and using a hose. It is very important not to penetrate the electronics with water. I was careful, and the unit survived, cooling better than ever. If you soak the push-button pad you may end up with an expensive and over-large paper weight on your hands.